# Add routes (IPs ?) to Windows Updates Servers (DNSs)

Tags: windows, networking, updates, static-routes

It is possible to add routes to Windows Udpate Servers?

I've this server which Default Gateway is an internal service interface, so all internet traffic is explicitly allowed via routes in the internet interface.

So when I want to update it, I need to temporaly change the DG for the internal interface to the internet interface.

I've read in various places how to interact with Windows Updates, but via DNS only, but I cannot add routes for DNSs, just Ips.

It is possible to configure the server so it keeps it's DG in the internal interface, and at the same time the Windows Updates traffic goes for the proper Gateway, via routes, or some other way?

Comment: No WSUS, Delivery optimization, etc..

Comment: Why not add routes for all internal networks via the internal service interface instead?

Comment: Without go to deep into details, the server must have the DG in the service interface to give service;  internet traffic in this server is pretty much limited to Windows udpates, really.